# How to get ALL selected items from ListBox into an EditBox?

Tags: delphi

I am experimenting (for the first time) with using a ListBox instead of a ComboBox to select strings, which will then populate an Edit box that will be used to build an SQL string.

I have the ListBox set to `MultiSelect` and `ExtendedSelect` both set to `True`.  However, when I run the code below, I am only getting a single selected item from the ListBox to the Edit box.

I have search and searched for the last 48 hours for help, but nothing works.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

```pascal
procedure TfrmQuery.lbSelectExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;    
begin 
  for i := 0 to lbSelect.SelCount -1 do
  begin
    if lbselect.selected[i] then
    begin
      edQryScript.Text := 'Select ' + lbSelect.items.Strings[i] + ' from ';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Take a piece of plywood and paint it entirely red. The next day, (re)paint it entirely green. The third day, (re)paint it entirely blue. The fourth day, (re)paint it entirely yellow. The fifth day, you wonder why it is yellow and not multi-coloured. In this case, you replace `edQryScript.Text` each time, so the previous value is overwritten.

Comment: (I don't want to be rude or anything, but searching the WWW for a solution isn't the right thing to do. The right thing to do is to buy a good book about Delphi programming and read it from the first page to the last page.)

Comment: Precisely "a single selected item" as you call it is always (in theory) the **last selected** item, hence the yellow plywood. But since your code logic is flawed it won't even be that - if you have 3 items, select the third and your code will pick none, since you only iterate until `.SelCount- 1` instead of `.Count- 1`.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Good point, I didn't even notice the incorrect upper bound.

Comment: Just to add a bit to @AndreasRejbrand & AmigoJack's good points, it would be more help (for you) to think of your problem in more abstract terms, e.g. how to generate a comma-delimited list by iterating over a TStrings object.

Comment: @MartynA, thank you.  My code was what I gleaned from looking at several examples. I need to read up more on the comma-delimited list.  I thank you for your time.  I am not a professional programmer, just a hobbyist for self-use. I tried to understand examples generating a stringlist, but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you select the fields that must appear in the `SELECT` clause from the ListBox and then compose the `SELECT` statement.

You are going through all the selected items, but you are only putting one each time inside of the `SELECT` and then, with the next iteration, you lose the previous information.

As @amigoJack mentions, I guess it is `lbSelected.Count` and not `lbSelected.SelCount` that would stop iterating when it has gone through the number of selected items and not the total number of items, among which it still has to decide whether it is selected or not (if `lbselect.selected[i] then ...`).

Try something like this:

```pascal
procedure TfrmQuery.lbSelectExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;    
begin 
  for i := 0 to lbSelect.Count -1 do
  begin
    if lbselect.selected[i] then
    begin
      if edQryScript.Text <> '' then
        edQryScript.Text := edQryScript.Text + ', ';
      edQryScript.Text := edQryScript.Text + lbSelect.items.Strings[i];
    end;
    edQryScript.Text := 'Select ' + edQryScript.Text + ' from ';
  end;
end;
```

So that every iteration adds the field to what was previously in `edQryScript.Text`.  It is easier to bother about the `Select ... from` when we already have all the fields to the `select` statement.

Comment: Note that a `TStringList` would be useful here, rather than doing a bunch of individual `Text` concatenations, eg: `var FieldNames: TStringList; i: integer; begin if lbSelect.SelCount = 0 then Exit; FieldNames := TStringList.Create; try for i := 0 to lbSelect.Count -1 do begin if lbselect.Selected[i] then FieldNames.Add(lbSelect.Items[i]); end; edQryScript.Text := 'Select ' + FieldNames.CommaText + ' from '; finally FieldNames.Free; end;`

Comment: This code suggestion works the best at what I'm tyring to do @Remy Lebeau.  thank you